# Visual Studio 2010 isn't loading my solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crash, loading

I have my development and my production environment, in both of them the solution worked well.

In my development environment, I made a change to the solution using a class of the .NET Framework 4.5, and in the Visual Studio 2013 works fine.

When I made that change in my other environment, which is using Visual Studio 2010, the solution won't load anymore, it just keep crashing at the loading.

I commented the lines that I think cause the problem with NP++, and now the solution loads, but when I try to open a file, it just crash again.

I installed .NET Framework 4.5.2 but still nothing, any idea?

Comment: What are the offending lines? Do you have version control to see what else may have changed?

Comment: .NET 4.5 is not supported on VS2010, AFAIK. But, it should not crash. Are other projects opening fine?

Comment: It would help if you did show the lines that you modified and the crash message text.